# Using BPY to get location of particle in keyed particle system

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine, particles

How can I get the location of a particle in a keyed particle system? I didn't find anything useful in the API documentation and thought I could post the question here.

I know I can get the location of a normal particle using:

```
for psys in obj.particle_systems:
    print(psys.particles[0].location)
```

But in a keyed particle system, the particle's `location` isn't the real / visible location. I thought I could use `particles[0].particle_keys.location`, but it only returns the location of the particles in the other `keys`. I also tried `particles[0].prev_location` but it returned an empty array.

Does anyone know how I can do this?