# Get location of keyed particles

Tags: python, particles, physics

I would like to know if its possible to get particle location, scale, rotation of particles used in keyed physics settings.

I've tried using location, but I believe this is only the location of the keys used.

```
name = psys.settings.dupli_object.name
package = Package()
package.name = name
package.alias = name
i = 0
for p in psys.particles:
    if (psys.settings.type == 'EMITTER' and p.alive_state == "ALIVE"):
        pm = p.rotation.to_matrix() * p.size
        frame = [pm[0][0], pm[0][1], pm[0][2], p.location[0],
                 pm[1][0], pm[1][1], pm[1][2], p.location[1],
                 pm[2][0], pm[2][1], pm[2][2], p.location[2]
                 ]
        package.addFrame(frame)
exporter.addPackage(package)
```

Do I need to make a calculation according to the key location? I'm not sure how I can reach the data of the particles in the keys

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/110898/using-bpy-to-get-location-of-particle-in-keyed-particle-system)